# C++ Can memory mapped files (boost::interprocess) move during program execution?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files

I read a large 5GB file like this:

Data members of class:

```
char* raw_bytes;
unsigned long long raw_bytes_size;
file_mapping* fm;
mapped_region* region;
unsigned long long file_offset;
MyClass co; (not including details of this as irrelevant)
```

Constructor:

```
FileReader::FileReader(const char* FilePath, unsigned long long file_offset_pos){
    fm = new file_mapping(FilePath, boost::interprocess::read_only);
    region = new mapped_region(*fm, boost::interprocess::read_only);
    raw_bytes_size = region->get_size();
    raw_bytes = static_cast<char*>(region->get_address());
    file_offset = file_offset_pos;
    Iterate(raw_bytes, raw_bytes_size);
}
```

Iterate through mapped file:

```
void FileReader::Iterate(char* rawbytes, unsigned long long size){
    unsigned long long i = file_offset;
    while(i < size){
        std::vector<char> order_bytes = co->getBytes(rawbytes, i);
    }
}
```

A different class to process each message (84 bytes long):

```
std::vector<char> B::getBytes(char* rawbytes, unsigned long long& pos){
    std::vector<char> bytes;

    int message_length = 84;
    unsigned long long last_pos = pos + message_length;

    bytes.reserve(message_length);
    while (pos < last_pos){                    
        bytes.push_back(rawbytes[pos]);   //The exception occurs here
        pos++;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Now if you look at this code carefully- it works fine. However, after say 500MB or 1GB I suddenly get an error thrown at `while (pos < last_pos)`. When the exception is thrown and Visual studio allows me to debug in an instance of VS, when I hover over the variables `last_pos` and rawbytes VS says they cannot be read, but the `memory` for pos can???? Its as if the underlying memory-mapped file has changed location halfway through processing.

NB: I have definitely not run out of RAM. Any suggestions?

The error message is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F86A05C in MyProgram.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000527533000.

- when I hover over `rawbytes` it says value: `0x0000000000000000`
- `pos` has the value `3825504`
- The original size of the file, `raw_bytes_size` was initially: `2554061585`

The call stack stopped at `B::getBytes()`

**UPDATE**: If I run this several times, each time I get the exception the value of `pos` (a position marker to read the next message) is different....  so its not because I have overran the file (plus `pos` is also MUCH smaller than the size of the file every time).

Comment: try to catch an exception? this may help

Comment: I wish I could downvote your comments, @piotruś.  Anyway, it may be helpful to verify that your pointer is being blasted, perhaps by saving its initial value and testing it with an `assert`.  VS is not always helpful with the "current value" rollover.  While not necessarily the problem, you do seem to have a potential buffer overrun: the loop that calls `getBytes` does not account for the number of bytes that will be examined past the current position (in other words, `getBytes` can be allowed to read past the end of the buffer).

Comment: @paddy sorry about that, you have to enjoy doing something else, maybe go to my profile and click the clickable item in my interest description

Comment: @paddy would it change anything if i ran in debug rather than release mode after i encounter the problem?

Comment: Are you compiling for a 64-bit architecture? (I believe some 32-bit programs can address >2GiB using PAE?)

Comment: @sehe yes compiling for 64-bit

Comment: @user997112 You could try running the debug build.  At least you could rely on the values you see while in break mode.  However, quite often you will have a bug in the release build that does not show up in a debug build, due to timing or undefined behaviour.  The simplest way to start catching these is to write simple log messages to a file at key parts of your program's execution.  You can write out specific values and see for yourself what's going wrong.  It seems to me that we shouldn't trust those values you put in your question, and I strongly suspect my earlier comment is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

No, the mmap doesn't spontaneously move (but it doesn't need to at the same address across remaps).

Try

```
if (size>=84) 
{
     while(i < (size-84))
     {
         std::vector<char> order_bytes = co->getBytes(rawbytes, i);
     }
}
```

To account for the (not unlikely?) occasion that the file is not a multiple of 84 at the time of mapping.

Comment: But pos (which is essentially a position marker) is much smaller than the size of the file.

Comment: I think you need to check that assumption. If that's not the problem, than you have "simple" memory corruption/[UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that modifies the pointer... (could it be that the file is rewritten/truncated after opening?)